# JPA SIngle table inheritance with normalized DiscriminatorColumn

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance, discriminator

I am using Hibernate as the JPA persistence provider.
I am only using JPA features, not hibernate specific ones.

With a single table inheritance, you have to have a `DTYPE` text field (default name or choose another name) to allow the persistence provider to map the data to the correct subclass.

The problem I see is that the table will hold that `DTYPE` field on each row and so it will contains useless string duplicates.

I would like to normalize the `DTYPE` field. That is to say, create a table which just holds a list of id and unique DTYPE string fields. Then, in the single inheritance table, the DTYPE field would be an foreign key pointing to the DTYPE table. The discriminator column would then be a foreign key.

**Is it possible to map such a normalized discriminator column with JPA ?**

Comment: If you're concerned about space occupied by the discriminator, why don't you just set the discriminatorType to CHAR or INTEGER? You can then set a foreign key constraint on the column if you want, and make it reference a table containing the name associated to each integer/char value.

Comment: @JBNizet I have thought of that, but that would mean that in the application code, the subclass should have its DiscriminatorValue to be the foreign key integer value. This is not good because the code shouldn't be aware of the database ids.

Comment: These IDs are not dynamically generated. They directly correspond to classes of your application. I think you should just use the simple solution: use integers. Making the code independant of the actual integer values used as discriminator value wouldn't bring any substantial advantage.